# Align end Quote with text at the end

Tags: html, alignment, double-quotes

I want to place end quote inline with the ending text like below.
[image]
but my HTML renders as below :: [image]

So, I want to place end quote in the last line.
But in some resolution it shows in the next line.

My HTML is

```
<span style="leftquote">
     <img alt="Quote" src="../../Images/Static/Quote_Start.png" class="startQuote" />    
</span>
<span class="contentSection">
    test text test text test text test text
    <img alt="Quote" src="../../Images/Static/Quote_End.png" class="endQuote" />
</span>
```

and below is my css::

```
.leftquote { display: inline; }
.startQuote
{
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float:left;
}

.contentSection
{
    display: block;
    width: 89%;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.endQuote
{
    vertical-align: text-top;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

So what may be the workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check my jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xGjD2/1/

```
<blockquote class="style3">
    <span>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </span>
</blockquote>
```

and Css :

```
blockquote.style3 {
      font: 18px/30px normal Tahoma, sans-serif;
      padding-top: 22px;
      margin: 5px;
      background-image: url(http://www.8p-design.com/templates/base/images/white/quote_left.png);
      background-position: top left;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      text-indent: 65px;
  }

  blockquote.style3 span {
      display: block;
      background-image: url(http://www.8p-design.com/templates/base/images/white/quote_left.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom right;
  }
```

Comment: Hi I checked your js fiddle. I checked it by adding "test1 test2 t" to your content,as a result it will show the same problem(quote in the next line).
(FYI :: My resolution is 1366 X 768)

Comment: Now it works even if it's not exactly the same result : http://jsfiddle.net/xGjD2/3/. With your code, the image behaves as a character and it's normal if it goes to the next line.

Comment: @Danovan :: tried your solution again, in that you have provided position to image. so it will remain at bottom right side.(which is not expected).
also I have checked by adding some content.
after adding this extra text, it shows text and end quote overlapping each other.(which is not expected).